# How can I convert a Darknet label file to regular x,y,w,h?

Tags: javascript, darknet

I'm sorry to ask this here but I have been at it for days and I can't figure out what formula to use. I'm hoping someone knows what i can do, thanks!

So I am trying to make a GUI tool for darknet but the little squares shown in the front are in the wrong position.

[image]

Image Dimensions : `1024 x 683`
Annotation Line in Label File : `0 0.6681250000000001 0.510788 0.09750000000000003 0.15103200000000006`

I am trying to get `x,y,w,h` like this

```
    var convertDarknetImageLabelsToMatrices = function(loadedImage){
        // loadedImage = {
        //     annotation: "0 0.6681250000000001 0.510788 0.09750000000000003 0.15103200000000006",
        //     dimensions: {
        //         height: 683,
        //         width: 1024
        //     }
        // }
            var width = loadedImage.dimensions.width
            var height = loadedImage.dimensions.height
            var matrices = []
            var labels = loadedImage.annotation.split('\n')
            labels.forEach(function(label){
                if(!label)return
                var lineParts = label.split(' ')
                var classNumber = lineParts[0]
                var x = lineParts[1] * width / 2
                var y = lineParts[2] * height / 2
                var w = lineParts[3] * width
                var h = lineParts[4] * height
                matrices.push({
                    classNumber: classNumber,
                    tag: loadedImage.className,
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    w: w,
                    h: h,
                    imageWidth: width,
                    imageHeight: height
                })
            })
            return matrices
    }
```

the parsing part is

```
                var x = lineParts[1] * width / 2
                var y = lineParts[2] * height / 2
                var w = lineParts[3] * width
                var h = lineParts[4] * height
```

I added the `/2` because it seems to make it closer. On some images it will be almost exact on a single axis, like X will line up but Y will be way off. I've tried to figure a static formula but its just always off in some other direction whenever opening another image.

Training itself is fine, I just can't edit/view the boxes later in the UI :(

thank you! if you need more info please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all who viewed and considered answering. I just figured it out! here is what I need to use for parsing.

```
                var w = lineParts[3] * width
                var h = lineParts[4] * height
                var x = (lineParts[1] * width) - w / 2
                var y = (lineParts[2] * height) - h / 2
```